# Sending Query Parameters encoded in a URI on a Post which also has json

Tags: java, json, http-post, urlencode

I have a server that handles a POST request with JSON. It also looks and decodes query parameters from the URI. My Java Client currently uses HTTPPost to send across the Json with ContentType application/json.

I wonder whehther [URLEncodeUtil](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) method format would be able to accomplish this. Except the documentation mentions

> suitable for use as an application/x-www-form-urlencoded list of
>   parameters in an HTTP PUT or HTTP POST.

So my question is 
1. Would this work with ContenType set to application/json.
2. Is there another way to accomplish what the Server requires, ie: have JSON as well as Query parameters encoded in the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two official methods of posting form data via the ([HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)).  The pertinent value is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which adds a `?` along with the name/value pairs encoded in the URL.  If the form method is POST then it will be the first line after the HTTP POST statement.

Everything we do with HTTP in REST web services is valid HTTP, but not for HTML.  So the `application/json` can have a combination of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` style parameters and the JSON payload.

The HTTP request will look something like this:

```
POST /blog/posts?myparam=Something%20Good&token=donotdothis
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 57

{"title":"Hello World!","body":"This is my first post!"}
```

Also spelled out here: http://www.jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-over-http.html

It's the `?` that marks the beginning of extra parameters.  So while that is technically legal, it does beg the question why everything you need to post can't be part of your JSON.  The downside of this approach is that the query parameters are all part of your HTTP logs and is very visible.  You definitely should not use this approach with passwords or any other personally identifiable information.  Depending on privacy laws in your country, you want to minimize unnecessary records to make compliance much easier.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!